# How to model "Lazy" field in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, lazy-evaluation, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net for serialization. I have a class which contains a "Lazy" field, how to set it up and make the test case work? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
[Fact]
public void LazyField()
{
    MetaType metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(WithLazyField), true);
    metaType.UseConstructor = false;
    ValueMember metaField = metaType.AddField(1, "_lazyField");
    metaField.AsReference = true;

    var obj = new WithLazyField();

    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    Assert.Equal(obj.GetValue(), clone.GetValue());
}

public class WithLazyField
{
    private readonly Lazy<double> _lazyField;

    public WithLazyField()
    {
        _lazyField = new Lazy<double>(() => Calculate());
    }

    public double Calculate()
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    public double GetValue()
    {
        return _lazyField.Value;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Lazy" type can be supported through surrogate